# Using a CursorLoader to create and ArrayList of objects from database

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I'm creating an app that is pretty much a menu for a restaurant, and I need to access the SQLite database to get all of the menu items.  I have a Content Provider set up with a SQLiteOpenHelper, and right now I need to figure out how to retrieve all of the menu items in the db and save them into an ArrayList of menuItem objects.  It seems like a CursorLoader would be the best option here, and I'm just a little confused on how to implement it.  Most of the posts I read have examples using a SimpleCursorAdapter, but they always end up just displaying the data in a list view, which I need to do eventually but I also need to save the data into individual objects.  Do I need to use a SimpleCursorAdapter, or can I just have a loop in the onLoadFinished method which keeps moving to the next cursor position and saving the data in an index of the ArrayList?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: if you dont need to display the data you dont need SimpleCursorAdapter and you can just loop in onLoadFinished like you said

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the database wrapped with the ContentProvider. You have most of the work done. Use a Cursor loader to get the data from the ContentProvider. The advantage of using the CursorLoader is that the loader created with initLoader() stays in memory thanks to the LoaderManager. If you need to separate the data in groups, you can create different loaders that will be available in the LoaderManager for whenever you want to use them.

The simpleCursorAdapter is used to fill a ListView with the cursor returned from the CursorLoader. If your listView items are complex (with buttons and imageView) you can create your custom Adapter extending CursorAdapter class.